# android, gradle process ExecException jdk1.8.0_25 finished with non-zero exit value 1?

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

How to solve this problem,

android org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

build.gradle file ::

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android  {

 compileSdkVersion 16

 buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.newventuresoftware.waveformdemo"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

repositories {
   maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile "commons-io:commons-io:+"
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
   compile project (':waveform')
}
```

the whole error from message tab

```
Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
... 12 more
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
 Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
... 12 more
 2 errors; aborting
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
 > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Thanks..

Comment: try `cleaning` the project

Comment: set `compileSdkVersion 23`

Comment: `compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"`

Comment: @Samer Alshurafa : There will be error message at `Message` window in your Android studio. Please post whole error here..!!

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya 
I try you suggestions but it does not solve the problem !!

Comment: @SamerAlshurafa solve yet ? call `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`

Answer (score 0):

try add this in your build.gradle,then clean & rebuild.

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    preDexLibraries = true
}
```

Comment: It run successfully after I remove this :: compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

Comment: well,my JavaVersion is VERSION_1_7.I have solved a similar problem by adding those.